# Is there a way to publish rdl reports programmatically with C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, rdl

I have a solution file in BI that contains 10 report projects. I publish these projects manually with every change. I want to know that is there a solution to deploy these projects on report server programmatically?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Use the API: [ReportOperationsCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reportingservices.interfaces.reportoperation%28SQL.90%29.aspx) class

This is what VS uses

Comment: Unfortunately, the documentation for this is woefully inadequate. Are you aware of any code samples? None are turning up in search.

Answer (score 1):

We use TeamBuild that comes with M$ TFS.  Works like a charm, except we had to write a custom build task to transform the data sources.

Comment: Are you able to provide more details?