# deploy a reports project

Tags: c#, sql-server, reporting-services, rdl

I have a ReportsApplication and a WpfApplication.
I Want Deploy Reports in ReportsApplication with WpfApplication.
How can deploy a report in ReportsApplication with C# ?

Comment: maybe duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323593/is-there-a-way-to-publish-rdl-reports-programmatically-with-c