# Automatically Deploying Reporting Services Reports Via WPF (C#) Application (SQL Express 2008 R2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am working on a project which requires me to create an installer application using WPF and ClickOnce to install my website and the required prerequisites on a remote users laptop. As part of this Installer program I need to automatically deploy/update Reports, Dataset and Data Sources to the remote users Reporting Services (SQL Express 2008 R2); I have found the following thread [Publish rdl Reports Programmatically with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323593/is-there-a-way-to-publish-rdl-reports-programmatically-with-c) but the answer didn't explain how to achieve this and just points to the API.

Thank you in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out RSBuild project on codeplex (http://rsbuild.codeplex.com/). It is old but still points out the various aspects of SSRS task automation.

Comment: I have downloaded the RSBuild and modified the .config file as detailed in the RSBuild Configuration Guide; it runs and doesn't seem to error, but when I check in the reporting services webpage none of the DataSources or Reports have been deployed.

Comment: I was pointing out to this project for it's source code, not necessarily the entire project.